# Run 'login_footer' hook only for login processes

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, hook

Inside wp-login.php we have several `action`  process: 'logout', 'register', 'retrievepassword', etc... and of course 'login'.

I am using the `login_footer` hook to add some special features right after the "login form"

```
add_filter('login_footer', array($this, 'special_form'));
```

How can I decide when just `login` process is running? So I can avoid show the `special form` in other actions ('register', 'retrievepassword', etc...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "login_form_login" hook.

```
add_action('login_form_login', array($this, 'enable_special_form'));

/*... */

function enable_special_form() {
    add_action('login_footer', array($this, 'special_form'));
}
```

There's also a bunch of other `login_form_*` hooks for other wp-login.php actions - login_form_logout, login_form_register, and so on.

For reference, in WordPress 3.4.1 the login_form_* action is executed on line 380 of wp-login.php, and the available actions are listed on line 357.

Answer (score 0):

Checking `wp-login.php` file we see that `$action` is found in this way:

```
$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : 'login';
```

So with the following code I can to know what action is running:

```
add_filter('login_init', array($this, 'login_init'));   
function login_init()
{
    $action              = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : 'login';
    $this->login_running     = $action == 'login' ? true : false;
}
```

In order to use it in subsequent hooks like `login_message`, `login_footer`, etc...